# Tiny Java library to roughly guess country from latitude/longitude

Tags: open-source, library, java, offline, geocoding

I develop an Android app that lets people upload a picture and tag it. When the picture's EXIF data has GPS coordinates in Japan, I would like to add #japan to the tag suggestions.

Requirements:

- 100% Java library
- Input: latitude, longitude
- Output: Country name in English (even better if other languages are available)
- Size: Below 2 MB, as it is not a central feature and I want to keep the app small (the whole app is currently 2MB)
- Precision: About 100 kilometers.
- Response time: Less than half second even on a cheap phone
- Must work offline
- Free and open source

Tolerance:

- In border areas, giving several countries is OK, for instance for a picture taken in Luxembourg (tiny country) it could suggest France,Germany,Luxembourg,Belgium. Giving only one suggestion is OK too.
- Out-of-date borders is not a big problem. No update mechanism is needed as the app itself gets updated quite regularly.
- Behavior at sea is not important, so using one big rectangle (or circle) for New Zealand is OK, for instance.

*Keyword: reverse geocoding*

Answer (score 2):

6 years later, still no such library, so I just created one and released it as open source:

https://github.com/coordinates2country/coordinates2country

- Works offline
- Response time: Less than 100 milliseconds
- Size: 100 kilobytes
- Does not hoard any RAM
- Precision is about 0.2 degrees

## Example usage:

`Coordinates2Country.country(50.1, 10.2)` returns `"Germany"`.